# Erro de referência

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

Olá, eu copiei uma solution de uma pasta para outra e começou a dar alguns erros de referencia, é uma aplicação Asp.Net que tem um projeto Web API.

Na pasta original a aplicação está rodando normal, na pasta da cópia quando abro a solution e tento dar um rebuild da erro, as anotações de Route que existem nos métodos do controller da Web API ficam vermelho como se nao estivessem encontrando a referencia.

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obrigado.

Comment: Fora da pasta original, não tem uma pasta chamada **packages**?

Comment: Aliás, você atualizou os pacotes da solução antes de tentar fazer o *build*?

Comment: Se você postasse o erro ao dar um rebuild ajudaria..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na referência da dll do Asp.Net Web API estava apontando para a pasta do .Net Framework no C:, instalei o Web API no projeto pelo NuGet e resolveu.